# Go Daddy 403 page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ip, http-status-code-403

I tried to block an ip in the .htaccess, which I could do but I can't get the default 403 error to redirect to my custom 403 page. 
 Anyone know how to do this?

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403/403.html
```

Comment: Is your 403 page in a folder called 403?

Comment: Yes. And the file is called 403.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.html

order allow,deny 
deny from xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
allow from all
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be denying access to the file when you block the IP in the .htaccess file.

Create another `.htaccess` file inside the `403` directory and in that `.htaccess` allow all from anyone. Then anyone should be able to see the custom 403.html page when they are blocked.

See if that will help your issue.

**Update:**

Here is an example.

Put the error document line in the **root** .htaccess file.

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403/403.html
```

Then in the .htaccess file inside the `403` directory add only this.

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Comment: it didn't work  heres my code: `ErrorDocument 403 /403.html

order allow,deny
allow from all`

Comment: @Peter you could provide an upvote since my answer helped you to figure out doing it the way you wanted. Both answers will work for people depending on their needs.

Comment: @Peter what are talking about. I never down voted you. I don't down vote for no reason. Also I deducts from me too if I do that. Where did you get that??

Comment: I'm current;y only at 14 points. but I would vote you, but I cant

Answer (score 0):

- Browser Cache? http://pcsupport.about.com/od/browsers/f/clear-cache.htm
- HTTP-Server restart (I don't know how it works by GoDaddy)
- Is it the right path to the Error-HTML file? /403/403.html (try the absolute path?)

Comment: you can't restart the server at GoDaddy, and the path is right and my browser cache is cleared